# Configure IIS To Verify Client Certificate using external OCSP

Tags: iis, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, ocsp

I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 environment that hosts a website in IIS. The website currently requires a client certificate (which is validated) to access the website.

The client certificate is checked to ensure that it is valid and has not been revoked, not for identification by the operating system. If the user presents a valid certificate, the information on the certificate is used to authenticate and identify the user in the application code (the actual authentication is Forms Authentication). There is no mapping of the client certificate to an individual user (e.g. the client certificates does not map to an active directory account).

The site currently utilizes an additional piece of software to pass the client certificate to an external OCSP to verify the certificate status.

My goal is to remove that additional piece of software and be left with an IIS only (or Windows Server only) solution, but the documentation has me confused. I'm not sure if I need to install the OCSP role on the IIS server or our AD server, or if there is a way in IIS to configure a URL to check the certificate.

Comment: In IIS, client certificate authentication MUST map to some entity, otherwise IIS will reject the certificate before it reaches your application.

Comment: Without additional software, you need at least OCSP Stapling.When enabled a server pre-fetches the OCSP response for its own certificate and delivers it to the user’s browser during the TLS handshake.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ocsp-stapling

Answer (score 0):

If the client certificate is pointing to an OCSP server in its extension, IIS will automatically validate it. You might check the `CAPI2\Operational` event log to see what happens during the validation.